# Can htaccess be used to deny ALL unless the request contains my site's domain name?

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

After viewing my site's logs, I've noticed that at least half of the questionable log entries are accessing the site by the server's IP address (instead of by the domain name).

I would like to deny access to my entire website *unless* the request contains my site's domain name. For example:

- ALLOWED: www.mysite.com/any/directory/depth/index.php
- ALLOWED: mysite.com/any/directory/depth/index.php
- ALLOWED: images.mysite.com/any/directory/depth/thumbnails.php
- DENIED: 123.456.789.101/
- DENIED: 123.456.789.101/all/other/directories/
- DENIED: 123.456.789.101/all_files_too.php

I've seen other examples that will *rewrite* an IP request so that it becomes the actual domain name. However... for my purposes, I'd like my Apache/2.2.24 server to simply display the standard "403 Forbidden" message.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try adding in the htaccess file in your document root:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !mysite\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ - [L,F]
```

Another option is to edit your vhost configuration files by creating a specific vhost for the `mysite.com` hosts, then create a default vhost (should be the first one) that simply has a

```
Deny from all
```

in it.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. The RewriteCond directive you suggested is successful in prohibiting access if the request is **only** the IP address.

However, if the request is the IP + filename, or IP + foldername, then the rewrite rule does not get applied.

123.456.789.101 (is denied)
123.456.789.101/somefolder/somefile.php (is allowed)

Comment: PS: I'll also do more research on the vhost file as you suggested.

Comment: @AllenW. do you have other rules? If so, the ones I posted need to be the very first ones in your file. It checks only the hostname, doesn't care what the URI is. The URI can be anything.

Comment: Yes indeed! That was it! I moved your RewriteCond and RewriteRule directives to the top of the .htaccess in the website root AND in the ecommerce directory root. IT WORKS PERFECTLY!! Thank you!